# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error de referencia en SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

me encuentro haciendo una tabla y me tira este error : Foreign Key references FK_Orders_codigoHash  references invalid table customers, a que se debe?

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
    ordersID int NOT NULL,/*HEREDA*/
    OrderTotal smallint NOT NULL,
    OrderStatusID int NOT NULL,/*HEREDA*/
    OrderDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ordersID),
    customerID int  REFERENCES customers(customerID)
)
```

La tabla de la cual quiero hacer la relacion es:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   customerID int NOT NULL,
   phoneNumber char(10) NOT NULL,
   [name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
   adress nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
   city nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   state char(2),
   PRIMARY KEY(customerID)
   9
```

Comment: Tienes un `9` en lugar del paréntesis final de la creación de `customers`, no será  que no existe `customers` cuando intentas crear `orders`?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que necesitas crear primero la tabla `customers` para poder referenciar una de sus columnas.  Sigue este orden:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   customerID int NOT NULL,
   phoneNumber char(10) NOT NULL,
   [name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
   adress nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
   city nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   state char(2),
   PRIMARY KEY(customerID)
   )

CREATE TABLE orders(
    ordersID int NOT NULL,/*HEREDA*/
    OrderTotal smallint NOT NULL,
    OrderStatusID int NOT NULL,/*HEREDA*/
    OrderDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ordersID),
    customerID int  REFERENCES customers(customerID)
)
```